# Divide each value by the sum of values by group

Tags: r, dataframe, sum

I have the following data frame, where "x" is a grouping variable and "y" some values:

```
dat <- data.frame(x = c(1, 2, 3, 3, 2, 1), y = c(3, 4, 4, 5, 2, 5))
```

I want to create a new column where each "y" value is divided by the sum of "y" within each group defined by "x". E.g. the result for the first row is 3 / (3 + 5) = 0.375, where the denominator is the sum of "y" values for group 1 (x = 1).

Answer (score 22, accepted):

There are various ways of solving this, here's one

```
with(dat, ave(y, x, FUN = function(x) x/sum(x)))
## [1] 0.3750000 0.6666667 0.4444444 0.5555556 0.3333333 0.6250000
```

Here's another possibility

```
library(data.table)
setDT(dat)[, z := y/sum(y), by = x]
dat
#    x y         z
# 1: 1 3 0.3750000
# 2: 2 4 0.6666667
# 3: 3 4 0.4444444
# 4: 3 5 0.5555556
# 5: 2 2 0.3333333
# 6: 1 5 0.6250000
```

Here's a third one

```
library(dplyr)
dat %>%
  group_by(x) %>%
  mutate(z = y/sum(y))

# Source: local data frame [6 x 3]
# Groups: x
# 
#   x y         z
# 1 1 3 0.3750000
# 2 2 4 0.6666667
# 3 3 4 0.4444444
# 4 3 5 0.5555556
# 5 2 2 0.3333333
# 6 1 5 0.6250000
```

Comment: `with(dat,y/ ave(y,x, FUN=sum))` would be a bit more compact.  One more option `dat$y/xtabs(y~x, dat)[dat$x]`

Comment: So in `dplyr`, the `sum` sums over the groups created by a previous `group_by`. Try with `dat <- data.frame(x=c(1,1,4,4,5,5,6,6), y=c(5,6,1,0,3,1,2,3))` then `dat %>% group_by(x) %>% group_by(y) %>% mutate(w = y/sum(x))` to see that the `group_by(x)` has no effect. Conversely, not grouping treats the whole data frame as the group: `dat %>%  mutate(w = y/sum(x))` computes relative weights summing to 1. Or `dat %>% mutate(rel_x = x/sum(x)) %>% summarize(total = sum(rel_x))` yields 1, as it should.

Comment: @DavidTonhofer What do you need?

Comment: @DavidArenburg Thanks David, I am clear on the sum-over-groups, I just wanted to wriet a note about something I tested.

Answer (score 3):

Here are some base R solutions:

**1) prop.table** Use the base `prop.table` function with `ave` like this:

```
transform(dat, z = ave(y, x, FUN = prop.table))
```

giving:

```
  x y         z
1 1 3 0.3750000
2 2 4 0.6666667
3 3 4 0.4444444
4 3 5 0.5555556
5 2 2 0.3333333
6 1 5 0.6250000
```

**2) sum**  This also works:

```
transform(dat, z = y / ave(y, x, FUN = sum))
```

Answer (score 1):

And of course there's a way for people thinking in SQL, very wordy in this case, but nicely generalising to all sorts of other similiar problems:

```
library(sqldf)
dat <- sqldf("
  with sums as (
    select
      x
      ,sum(y) as sy
    from dat
    group by x
  )
  select
    d.x
    ,d.y
    ,d.y/s.sy as z
  from dat d
  inner join sums s
    on d.x = s.x
")
```