# Reference value in different dataframes with common columns in R

Tags: r

I have made a group_by to obtain the sum of some values by other variabls and need now to obtain the weighted percentage of each of the values regarding this total sum.

I am sorry if this is too basic but I was thinking about the most optimal way to make this operation. I think I can manually add a column in the original dataframe and simply divide the two columns but when the dataset is large this won't work.

I hope with the example below it will be more clear:

```
myvector1 <- c(1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,2,2,2,2,2,2,2,2)
myvector2 <- c(1,1,1,2,2,2,3,3,1,1,1,2,2,2,3,3)
myvector3 <- c(1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8)
myvector4 <- c(rnorm(16))
mydf <- data.frame(myvector1, myvector2, myvector3, myvector4)
library(dplyr)
mycoeffs <- mydf %>% group_by(myvector1,myvector2) %>% summarize(mysum = sum(myvector4))
```

What I'd like to do in a good programming way (Sorry I am learning) is to create a column with the division of the differente values in mydf$myvector4 in the original df by the corresponding value of the sum that I have un mycoeffs$mysum.

Thank you and sorry for not being so clear, hope it is understable.

Comment: try this: `ave(mydf$myvector4, list(mydf$myvector1, mydf$myvector2), FUN= function(x) x/sum(x))`. Simply add the output using s.th. like `mydf$res <- ave(...`

Comment: Just change `summarise` with `mutate` i.e. `mydf %>% group_by(myvector1,myvector2) %>% mutate(mysum = myvector4/sum(myvector4))`

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Divide row value by aggregated sum in R data.frame](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30239229/divide-row-value-by-aggregated-sum-in-r-data-frame)

Comment: Thank you ! 

With the ave function it works. However with the mutate I obtain different values. Do not know what is exactly doing :( The values are somehow similar but not correct!